# Django/Python encoding - ''ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 52'

Tags: python, django, encoding

I started working on same project recently and I have noticed some strange problem I can't resolve.
After running Django developement server, and typing address into the browset I get following output in terminal:

```
[02/Oct/2012 00:38:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 482
[02/Oct/2012 00:38:09] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 349
[02/Oct/2012 00:38:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 482
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 146, in get_response
    response = debug.technical_404_response(request, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 432, in technical_404_response
    'reason': smart_str(exception, errors='replace'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 116, in smart_str
    return str(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 235, in __repr__
    return smart_str(u'<%s %s (%s:%s) %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.urlconf_name, self.app_name, self.namespace, self.regex.pattern))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Page is displayed properly and server is still working, but I think this is annoying. And I'm also curious what is this about.
So, after a while I figured out, that if I comment out second pattern in my urls.py the error message is no longer displayed. My urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'apps.articles.views.index', name='homepage'),
    url(r'', include('articles.urls', namespace='articles')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and apps/users/urls.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('articles.views',
    url(r'^articles/$', 'article_list', {'all': True}, name='article_list'),
)
```

I've also noticed, that my style.css file isd/*position: absolute;
  not working properly. I've set border aroun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your application name have non-ascii characters?

Comment: Name does not, but one of directories on a path did. Changing it solved the problem, but is there a way I can maintain my directories names?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, make sure you install `language-pack-xx` package, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

in order to provide English translation data updates for all supported packages (including Python).

---

Then make sure to set your locale settings right before running your script from the terminal, e.g.

```
$ locale -a | grep "^en_.\+UTF-8"
en_GB.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Docs: `man locale`, `man setlocale`.